# Cannot properly execute a sql script with sqlite3 Python module

Tags: python, mysql, sql, exception, sqlite

I'm trying to execute SQL scripts contained in a .sql file with the sqlite3 Python module, in order to migrate the database from a Drupal site to a Wordpress one.

So I open and read the .sql thing with this little script:

```
def executeSQLScriptsFromFile(filename):
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    sqlFile = fd.read()
    fd.close()

    sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')

    for command in sqlCommands:
        print " === BEGIN \n" + command + "\nEND === \n"
        try:
            c.execute(command)
        except OperationalError, msg:
            print "Command skipped: ", msg
```

And when I execute this code with SQL commands I write, everything works fine: CREATE TABLE, SELECT, DELETE...

But when I try with the SQL script that I downloaded from a website database I work on:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `node` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `promote` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `moderate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tnid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `translate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `node_changed` (`changed`),
  KEY `node_created` (`created`),
  KEY `node_moderate` (`moderate`),
  KEY `node_promote_status` (`promote`,`status`),
  KEY `node_status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
  KEY `node_title_type` (`title`,`type`(4)),
  KEY `node_type` (`type`(4)),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `tnid` (`tnid`),
  KEY `translate` (`translate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=663 ;
```

I got this exception:

```
Command skipped:  near "unsigned": syntax error
```

As you can see, I am not fluent in SQL :p

Does someone know what may be the problem ?

Comment: are you using sqlite3 or mysql? why is this tagged with both? basically that sql is likely targeting a different sql engine than the one you are using ...

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3 does not support "unsigned" and it does not support AUTO_INCREMENT.  there are probably some other directive that sqlite3 does not support ... I think that you got that file from someone who was targeting postgres or mysql... to fix it remove all directives that are not supported by sqlite3, or use the same database engine that file targets

as an aside you can do

```
 c.executescript(open("my_sqcript.sql").read())
```

here is the schema that will work for sqlite3

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `node` (
  `nid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `vid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `promote` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `moderate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tnid` int(10)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `translate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`),
  UNIQUE(`vid`)

)   ;
```

here is the table as defined by sqlalchemy

```
class Node(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'node'
   nid     = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
   vid     = Column(Integer,default=0)
   type    = Column(String,default="")
   language= Column(String,default="")
   title   = Column(String,default="")
   uid     = Column(Integer,default=0)
   status  = Column(Integer,default=1)
   created = Column(Integer,default=0)
   changed = Column(Integer,default=0)
   comment = Column(Integer,default=0)
   promote = Column(Integer,default=0)
   moderate= Column(Integer,default=0) 
   sticky  = Column(Integer,default=0)
   tnid    = Column(Integer,default=0)
   translate= Column(Integer,default=0)
```

Comment: So, what would be the best way and the simplest way to work with MySQL scripts in Python ?

Comment: convert it to an ORM like sqlalchemy, then it doesn't care about the backend engine, and in theory you can change it easily.    mysqldb i think is what every one uses to talk to mysql databases ... if you want to take raw sql written for mysql lots of it will probably break if you are just trying to use it with sqlite3